# How to use faker.date.between faker.js

Tags: javascript, faker

I want to generate some dates between two fixed values, but I don't know how to

use  `faker.date.between` to achieve that.

the example in [faker js demo](http://marak.com/faker.js/) is just giving a `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their code from [Github](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/lib/date.js) shows:

```
self.between = function (from, to) {
  var fromMilli = Date.parse(from);
  var dateOffset = faker.random.number(Date.parse(to) - fromMilli);

  var newDate = new Date(fromMilli + dateOffset);

  return newDate;
};
```

And I don't know how you're using it, or why it's not working on their example....  But this should give you some direction, at least.

If this does not help you, or is still producing an undesired result, I would open an issue up on their github.

Answer (score 25):

Not sure when did they update [wiki](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/wiki/Dates), but they do have a working sample for `date.between` now

```
faker.date.between('2015-01-01', '2015-01-05');
```

Comment: For those who end up here and wonder about the wiki link, try the official documentation at https://fakerjs.dev/api/date.html#between